# Подскажите по sudo bash

Tags: linux, xubuntu, install, sudo

Работаю в компании где на xubuntu установлены root права ( естественно ).
Вопрос, если я что-то устанавливаю через

- `sudo bash`
- `password *****`
- `apt-get install Atom.deb`

  1. Ничего не устанавливается =) ( пишет не найден такой пакет, хотя дистриб лежит на рабочем столе.
  2. Видят ли сис. админы или руководство мои действия ( как вы считаете ?)?

Comment: `Atom.deb` не похоже на путь к файлу, лежащему на рабочем столе

Comment: Нужно именно с путём указывать ?

Comment: С путем и использовать dpkg, а apt-get по-моему ставит из репозиториев

Comment: Есть статьи, как зачищать. Обычно это делается в логах (`/var/log/auth.log` - авторизация под судо туда свалится, `/var/log/messages` и других, для apt логи в `/var/log/apt`). Еще глянуть настройки сислога `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, `/etc/rsyslog.d/`. Потом history, для bash это ~/.bash_history (если с sudo) и `/root/.bash_history` если под рутом. А можно в такие команды первым писать пробел, тогда в хистори не сохраняется. Лучше статью прочитать чтобы понять, где, что чистить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> apt-get install Atom.deb
> ```

`apt` — это высокоуровневая часть системы установки ПО. В её задачи входит управление зависимостями и получение пакетов из репозитариев, отдельные пакеты она не устанавливает. Для установки отдельных пакетов в post-debian дистрибутивах используется пакетный менеджер `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -i Atom.deb
```

Если ругнётся на зависимости, то:

```
apt-get install -f
```

и повторить.

#### Другие замечания

> Видят ли сис. админы или руководство мои действия ( как вы считаете ?)?

Это к делу не относится, но если тебе дали root-доступ, то вероятней всего ни кто не заморачивался тем чтобы настраивать какую-либо инфраструктуру, чтобы следить за тобой, т.к. ты в любой момент можешь её снести... Но последствия твоих действий они почти наверняка увидят, если посмотрят.

> `sudo bash`

У `sudo` есть отдельный ключик для запуска новой оболочки:

```
sudo -s
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробный ответ !

Comment: Могу добавить, что в свежей убунте лучше ставить через `apt install /local/path/to/deb`. Если нужны какие-то зависимости - они притянутся автоматом.

Comment: Нормальные админы запрещают вызов всех оболочек напрямую— хочешь суперпользователя, запускай каждую команду через sudo, а это уже мониторить легко.

Comment: @0andriy, только если дать пользователю только отдельный набор (на практике не больше 5) конкретных скриптов на исполнение... иначе — это лишь театр безопасности и мартышкин труд...